# How to validate credentials from Active Directory in a UWP application

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm using C# and VS 2019 to write an UWP app and I need access Active Directory information to validate the user password.

In a C# Windows Forms app, it works fine: I used the `ValidateCredentials` method from the `System.Directory.AccountManagement` namespace.

How can I do that in UWP?

I am using visual studio 2019 now, I did the upgrade from vs 2015 to 2019.

I installed `System.ServiceModel.Security` nuget package, but there is not much information how to use that library.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `System.Directory.AccountManagement` namespace does not support in UWP platform. And `System.ServiceModel.Security` nuget does not apply to UWP platform too.

In general, we use [Credential locker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/credential-locker) to validate user. However, those user name and password is create by the app but not the windows ad(Active Directory). Even if we could use `User.FindAllAsync()` to get current account, but we have not api to validate the user password. If you want to use your current account to login your app, you could try to use [Web Account Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-account-manager) to  request a user's permission to use their Microsoft account, obtain an access token.

For your scenario, you could use [desktop-bridge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop/) to make desktop extension for the UWP app and validate credentials in wpf or winform component and pass the result back to uwp with [AppService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service). For the deatil steps please google stenfan's blog UWP with Desktop Extension – Part 2.

Comment: Tanks Nico Zhu!